# Google Maps Android MapView v2: disable zooming

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way to disable the zooming (pinch and double tap) in the `MapView` but keep the scrolling?

This means setting clickable to false would not work.

I have also tried setting an `onTouch listener` in the `activity` but it will not trigger using:

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can assign those properties using the `XML` file:

```
   map:uiRotateGestures="true"
   map:uiScrollGestures="true"
   map:uiTiltGestures="true"
   map:uiZoomGestures="true"
```

So use:

```
   map:uiZoomGestures="false"
```

On the `MapFragment` object.

Comment: This solution did not work when adding the above code to my Map Fragment in the xml. @JRichardsz answer is correct. After implementing "map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);" I successfully disabled zoom.

Answer (score 27):

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
...
map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```

[UiSettings Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings#setZoomGesturesEnabled%28boolean%29)

Comment: This is the RIGHT ANSWER!! Thanks @laalto

Answer (score 4):

here is example on **Kotlin:**

```
map.uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

U may also try some thing like that ..

**NOTE : this method disables zoom in / out functionality for Google map UI**

**Above two answer is correct as per question asked. Thanks David for updating me.**

```
GoogleMap myMap;

myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

For more public methods available for Google Map UI ..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings#setZoomControlsEnabled(boolean)

Comment: This does not disable pinch zoom and/or double tab zooming, it only disables the +/- zoom buttons that are displayed by default on a map.

Comment: yup David .. It doesn't disables pinch property .. By mistake I mentioned this answer. My solution disables zooming option from UI. Answer mentioned above is correct. Also answer by laato is more precise. Thanks for updating me. Updating with new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution in Google Maps for Compose you can use this one:

```
GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    uiSettings = MapUiSettings(
        scrollGesturesEnabled = false,
        zoomGesturesEnabled = false,
        zoomControlsEnabled = false
    )
)
```