# How to disable zoom in googlemap in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I used googlemap in my project.  I doesn't wish to zoom map in any case. I wish to disable zooming when swipe on screen. I  used,

```
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

But it did not useful to me. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878616/google-maps-android-mapview-v2-disable-zooming?

Comment: No. now I tried.  But I got error  when putting this in xml.  map:uiZoomGestures="false". I got errors like attribute missing the android namespace prfix. how can I solve it? @shyam

Comment: @shyam K thanks. I got this with map.getUiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(false); I have one more doubt. Is there any possibility to touch disable on googlemap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean with "it did not useful to me"? What you posted is correct as it will disable the zoom controls. But you probably also need to disable the gestures so

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```