# Detect double click while using SupportMapFragment from com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using a SupportMapFragment to show a map in one of my views. 
Apart from that I'm listening to clusters click events, so I can center and zoom a map on cluster location when it's clicked.

The problem is that when the user double clicks on a map or even on a cluster item, a default "double tap detector" is triggered, map is moved towards the direction of a click and gets zoomed in a little.

In the worse scenario, if our clicked cluster is close to the edge of the map and it also splits into smaller clusters or markers -> some or all markers that emerged from it are placed outside the map area and they're not visible to the user.

I would like to handle this "default double tap event" in the same manner as I'm dealing with a cluster click.

Double tap gesture is one of default zoom gestures (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/controls)

Comment: Just disable zoom gestures. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878616/google-maps-android-mapview-v2-disable-zooming

Comment: @Jacek It is not an option. I just want to handle this default tap behaviour specifically.